# to gain SQL Server performance can I use something like set-based SQL with INSERT to temp-table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a 20 second Query from this Function, which is using a Cursor, While-Loop, AND calls another function.

Based on the code shown - what would be the best way to improve the performance of this bottleneck?

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetForUser] (@UserName VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS @User TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,Name VARCHAR(40)
    ,ParentID INT
    ,CompanyID INT
    ,CompanyName VARCHAR(100)
    ,CompanyDisplayName VARCHAR(100)
    ,AnotherID INT
    ,AnotherName VARCHAR(50)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @List TABLE (
        ID INT
        ,Name VARCHAR(40)
        ,ParentID INT
        )

    DECLARE List CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT ID
    FROM YourTable WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE CompanyID IN (
            SELECT companyid
            FROM UserToCompany
            WHERE UserName = @UserName
            )

    DECLARE @ID AS INT

    OPEN List

    FETCH List
    INTO @id

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @List
        SELECT *
        FROM ufnIncludeWithChildren(@ID)

        FETCH List
        INTO @ID
    END

    CLOSE List

    DEALLOCATE List

    INSERT INTO @User
    SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
        ,a.Name
        ,a.ParentID
        ,c.CompanyID
        ,c.CompanyName
        ,c.CompanyDisplayName
        ,d.AnotherID
        ,d.AnotherName
    FROM @List a
    JOIN YourTable b ON a.ID = b.ID
    JOIN CompanyInfo c ON b.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
    JOIN Anothers d ON b.AnotherID = d.AnotherID

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Oh man... The first rule is to never ever use cursors. The one in your procedure could easily be replaced with a WHILE loop. I'll see if I can optimize it.

Comment: @Ruslan and the second rule is Use FAST_FORWARD if all you're doing is looping

Comment: @ConradFrix That's cool, good to know! I try to avoid them altogether whenever possible, though. Up to this day, I never saw a use case where they couldn't be replaced with another construct (even in really complex procedures with 10k+ LOC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a single select.

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetForUser] (@UserName VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS @User TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,Name VARCHAR(40)
    ,ParentID INT
    ,CompanyID INT
    ,CompanyName VARCHAR(100)
    ,CompanyDisplayName VARCHAR(100)
    ,AnotherID INT
    ,AnotherName VARCHAR(50)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @User
        SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
            ,a.Name
            ,a.ParentID
            ,c.CompanyID
            ,c.CompanyName
            ,c.CompanyDisplayName
            ,d.AnotherID
            ,d.AnotherName
        FROM UserToCompany u
        JOIN CompanyInfo c ON u.CompanyID = c.CompanyID 
        CROSS APPLY ufnIncludeWithChildren(yt.ID) a
        JOIN YourTable b ON a.ID = b.ID
        JOIN Anothers d ON b.AnotherID = d.AnotherID
        WHERE u.UserName = @UserName
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: thanks! Trying it out now. One problem is that there is not a c.ID so I am trying to see how you did this.

Comment: @JoJo OK, I see. That table was originally missing it's name. I think the update to my answer addresses this.

Comment: Great! I think the JOIN <TABLE> b ON yt.ID = b.ID is not representing a table?

Comment: Hi! The Select DISTINCT query with the table joins took 4 minutes to run.

Comment: @JoJo This is where you need to start reviewing execution plans.  I don't see anything inefficient about my SQL, so without a SQL Fiddle with sample data, I'm not sure how much more I could help.

Comment: Okay, for clarity do you agree JOIN <TABLE> b ON yt.ID = b.ID should come out?

Comment: @JoJo Well... your original posting had "JOIN  b ON a.ID = b.ID". What table is missing there?

Comment: Ok sorry, I really blundered that original source code post. I fixed it. It should be YourTable

Answer (score 2):

On first glance, we can definitely eliminate the `CURSOR`. While replacing it with a `WHILE` loop as in my comment is one solution, we can go a step further and eliminate the loop completely by using an `APPLY` clause to call the function directly against each value in the row.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetForUser] (@UserName VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS @User TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,Name VARCHAR(40)
    ,ParentID INT
    ,CompanyID INT
    ,CompanyName VARCHAR(100)
    ,CompanyDisplayName VARCHAR(100)
    ,AnotherID INT
    ,AnotherName VARCHAR(50)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @List TABLE (
        ID INT
        ,Name VARCHAR(40)
        ,ParentID INT
        )

    INSERT INTO @List
    SELECT sfn.*
    FROM YourTable yt WITH (NOLOCK)
    CROSS APPLY ufnIncludeWithChildren(yt.ID) sfn
    WHERE yt.CompanyID IN (
            SELECT companyid
            FROM UserToCompany
            WHERE UserName = @UserName
    )

    INSERT INTO @User
    SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
        ,a.Name
        ,a.ParentID
        ,c.CompanyID
        ,c.CompanyName
        ,c.CompanyDisplayName
        ,d.AnotherID
        ,d.AnotherName
    FROM @List a
    JOIN  b ON a.ID = b.ID
    JOIN CompanyInfo c ON b.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
    JOIN Anothers d ON b.AnotherID = d.AnotherID

    RETURN
END
```

This code is not tested but should work. Please let me know if you have any issues.

Also, in your question you omitted the table name from the first query (where you had the cursor), so I put in `YourTable` in there as a placeholder.

Comment: (sometimes '@R'u.. does not bring up the Users name) Awesome - I do not understand what CROSS APPLY is.. so I am looking into it now. Thanks, I will let you know how the performance is!

Comment: Great! Please do. APPLY is a way to execute a function against each row of the result; its kind-of like using a sub-query, but in many cases its magnitudes of times faster (I've seen 1000x performance gains) because it lets SQL Server optimize it better. There is CROSS APPLY (exclude rows that don't return a result) and OUTER APPLY (like a LEFT JOIN but against a function).

Comment: @SpectralGhost's answer is even better because it goes a step further and eliminates the 'List' temporary table entirely. It is otherwise the same optimization but taken another step further. So his solution should be even faster

Comment: Oh my!!.. near instant now on the web app!! I have MUCH to learn here from just your one example. I DO basic CRUD operations myself so I am still learning, and this is not my original ufnFunction.

Comment: @JoJo Yep, optimizing SQL is actually very fun once you get into it. At one of my old (SQL heavy) jobs we had a dashboard on the screen with average execution times for all the stored procedures in the system (tens of thousands), and developers would get rewarded for optimizing the longest running ones :-) It becomes second nature once you optimize a few!

Comment: update this actually is about 14 seconds from the web app! BUT STILL this is an improvement of 6 seconds! :)

Comment: @JoJo How much data is being returned? Of course everything depends on your specific use case, etc., but nothing should take 14 seconds unless it is a massive amount of data... Have you looked at the execution plans to make sure that all indexes are in place?

Comment: @JoJo You should also isolate each part to find out exactly where the bottleneck is... Is it one of the JOINs? Is it the ufnIncludeWithChildren function? Is it one of the selects? Once you know, you can focus on finding the bottleneck in that specific part.

Comment: I know how to look at execution plans on a simple query but cannot run a Function from SSMS as I would have to keep updating an ID variable somehow?

Comment: @JoJo What do you mean? Can't you just do a test run like "SELECT * FROM ufnGetForUser('TestUserName')" and get the execution plan for that?

Comment: yes I can do that if 1 record is sufficient to get an execution plan. I guess Load or data size is not considered?

Comment: @JoJo Oh, I see what you're saying. Technically it shouldn't matter, but having more data will make it easier to diagnose and see the bottleneck. How many records is that function typically run against? You can create a temp table or a table variable and populate it with dummy usernames, and then run the function against that temp table...